# Why PHP round my number when I use json_encode?

Tags: php, json

I need execute `json_encode()` and convert my original number from:

```
50610101800060384093800100001010000000056199999999
```

to

```
"50610101800060384093800100001010000000056199999999"
```

But it return

```
5.061010180006E+49
```

I tried this:

```
ini_set('precision', 30); //With 1, 30, 50, 100, 1000
ini_set('serialize_precision', -1);
'content' => json_encode($params, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
```

but doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: You should convert your number to string before using `json_encode()` and do not use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag.

Comment: Did you at least read what is the `precision`? How do you want to store such large numbers as [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), ever heard of the `PHP_INT_MAX` ?

Comment: It's being turned into scientific notation before you get to the json_encode. Your code you've displayed is missing the crucial part of where you are assigning the variable the large number, or where it's coming from, as that's where you need to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50610101800060384093800100001010000000056199999999 exceeds the value of the maximum integer in PHP and so it is promoted to a float and expressed in scientific notation.  The float result may be problematic for various reasons as the Manual explains in [warning about floating point precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

If you wish to express the value as if it were an integer you must encapsulate it in a string.  That string you may add zero to it but when you do so the result in scientific notation will refer to a float,  as follows:

```
<?php

$s = "50610101800060384093800100001010000000056199999999";

echo $s,"\n";

$x = $s + 0;

echo $x, "\n",is_float($x);
```

See [here](https://3v4l.org/IX0tV#output).

For more info in re PHP and floats, see [here](https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/php/).

On the other hand, if there were an array of numbers whose digits corresponded to the numerical display in the OP's post, you could write code as follows:

```
<?php
    $a = [5,0,6,1,0,1,0,1,8,0,0,0,6,0,3,8,4,0,9,3,8,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9];
    foreach($a as $e) {
       $e = (string) $e;
    }
    $foo = join($a);
    var_dump($foo);
    $foo = bcadd($foo, 1);
    var_dump($foo);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/hDVpK#output).

The reason this example works is because each array value is converted to a numerical string and then the individual elements are joined to form one very long numerical string.  [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) is an extension in PHP which supports arbitrary precision.  In this case, the bcadd() function adds one to the numerical string which results in the display of an incremented numerical string value.

Answer (score 2):

Try This [https://3v4l.org/biNJG][1]

If you want this output `"50610101800060384093800100001010000000056199999999"`
you may want to pass this Value as string after encoding the value to JSON using `json_encode`
An integer data type is a non-decimal number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

Rules for integers:

1. An integer must have at least one digit
2. An integer must not have a decimal point
3. An integer can be either positive or negative
4. Integers can be specified in three formats: decimal (10-based), hexadecimal (16-based - prefixed with 0x) or octal (8-based - prefixed with 0)